# Regex to extract phone number from string

Tags: regex, apex

What would the regex be to extract the telephone number from this:

> Inbound Call at 5:10:54 PM from 07970123123 (Ted Bundy)

or

> Inbound Call at 5:10:54 PM from 07970 123123 (Ted Bundy)

I would like to get:

> 07970123123

My attempt:

> ^[a-zA-Z]\s[0-24]:[0-59]:[0-59][a-z] ( [0-9] ) [a-zA-Z]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following RegEx pattern would search the whole string and look for 11 consecutive digits to return as match `$1`:

```
^.*(\d{11}).*$
```

You could get fancier with it and add leading and trailing spaces around the match, like the following:

```
^.*\s(\d{11})\s.*$
```

...or if the phone number might not always be 11 digits:

```
^.*\s(\d+)\s.*$
```

**UPDATE:** Adding Ahmed's contribution for range 11-14 and the possibility that the pattern to match contains spaces.

```
^.*\s([\d\s]{11,14})\s.*$
```

Comment: Thanks. If I needed the telephone number to be between 11 and 14 characters?

Comment: @Robs You can replace `{11}` with `{11,14}`. You might also consider using `\b` instead of `\s` if the phone number isn't always preceded and followed by a whitespace; for example, that would match inputs like `from:07970123123(Ted Bundy)`.

Comment: How would I get the telephone number if it has a space in it? `Inbound Call at 5:10:54 PM from 07970 123123 (Ted Bundy)` ?

Comment: RegEx offers a ton of flexibility, and you have a ton of options, depending on the consistency of the data you're searching.  If the data will always contain " from [PhoneNumber] ([Contact Name]", you could use that to help identify your result:

    ^.*\sfrom\s(\d+)\s\(.*$

Comment: Another way to go about it, modifying the original pattern while including what Ahmed added, is enclosing an expression in brackets to say that you expect a string between 11 to 14 characters that contains either a digit \d or whitespace \s: ^.*\s([\d\s]{11,14})\s.*$